# How to retrieve an UIManagedDocument from a known url / file path?

Tags: objective-c, url, uimanageddocument

My purpose is to retrieve a UIManagedDocument object from an known url and then open it.

Something like:

```
 UImanagedDocument *doc = retrieveDoc(url);
```

then, I can do something like:

```
 [doc openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success){ ....}];
```

Believe me I did search apple's documentation there is a only method called initialise with a given url. Yes, I init create and save it before, and later I just need pick it up. Any way to do this?

Hope any one could give hints, thanks

Comment: for example: "- (BOOL)readFromURL:(NSURL *)url error:(NSError **)outError" Is this should be a class method? Then it will be what I want...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be such a class method, but in apple's reference, I found the sample code for creating UIManagedDocument

```
 doc = [[UIManagedDocument alloc] initWithFileURL:docURL];
 if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[docURL path]]) {
[doc openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success){
    if (!success) {
        // Handle the error.
    }
}];
}
else {
[self addInitialData];
[doc saveToURL:docURL forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForCreating completionHandler:^(BOOL success){
    if (!success) {
        // Handle the error.
    }
}];
```

So, basically, every time I want retrieve a UIManagedDocument from a given url, I must init it first and then open it. Am I right?

Any way, this is the way what I found working till now.